# No Shadows In Game View - Shadows in Scene View

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am having issues with shadows and lighting.

In Scene View this is what I see when I zoom close to the level layout:

[image]

But when I am in Game View this is what I see:

[image]

And these are my camera settings:

[image]

How can I increase my shadow view so that the camera can see the shadows without being so close to the level? I am aiming for a top down sort of game and I don't want the camera being so zoomed in or close to the level. Am I missing something in my settings?

Comment: it maybe would be interesting for someone finding this to know which of the 3 points below was the solution to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1**.Make sure there is a **light** in the scene. **Directional Light** is fine.

**2**.Make sure that your **GameObject** has "*Cast Shadows*" and "*Receive Shadows*" checked.

**3**.Go to **Edit** > **Project Settings** > **Quality**.Increase the **Shadow Distance**. This setting depends on the scale of your Scene/3D model.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it seems that Step 3 was the best option, increasing the shadow distance. Many thanks!

Comment: @IainBlackwood I was wondering which one worked for you. You are welcome.

Comment: That was exactly it. I increased the size of my terrain, and therefore moved back the camera in order not to collide with the new terrain. Doing so, I needed to increase the Shadow Distance to let the camera see the casting shadows.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Step 3 was also my issue (after a lot of searching). I think "Shadow Distance"  makes a lot of folks (or at least me) think of "Length of the Shadow", but actually it is the distance from the camera at which shadows are cast. In a game with a very distant camera (mine is, top down) this removes shadows since they are outside of the distance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone will still get this problem. Someone will, eventually. In my quest of reducing game size, I changed the quality of the game, and I unchecked the high fidelity, so shadows weren't casting. The solution that worked for me was just to check the box. I'm happy now. So PROJECT SETTINGS >